# How to motion deblur an image using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, motion-blur

So I have been asked to motion deblur a frame captured from a video, I am kind of new to this deblur filters so need help. The video does not contain any noise, just a vertical motion blur. I am not allowed to use skimage, or any other library except cv2. It would be a great help even if what technique or function I have to use comes to know. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dfd/tutorial_motion_deblur_filter.html

Comment: @nathancy thank you for the suggestion but it's not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Motion Deblur Filter of opencv, if you specifically want to use opencv.
Following is the link to its documentation, which is fairly easy to understand:
http://amroamroamro.github.io/mexopencv/opencv/weiner_deconvolution_demo_gui.html

You can go for skimage as well. It has many function like deconvolution which can help in deblurring images.

Answer (score 1):

I think that for this kind of problem you have to use the recent deep learning techniques. They outperform the classical approaches. I recommend to look on github for a repository that would already provide a trained network that can deblur the same kind of blur that you have.

I never tried it, but [this could be a nice candidate](https://github.com/KupynOrest/DeblurGAN).